# When is an analog input amplifier needed?

Tags: amplifier, driver

I'm reading in values that are coming within the ADC's Vref range... 2.5V. Why do all of the datasheets recommend driver amplifiers and what is the purpose of this if the voltage is in range? Is this only applicable if the input signal is really small and needs to be amplified to the ADC range?

Comment: Probably is also used for ADC protection in case of overvoltage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several reasons to put a amplifier between the input signal and a A/D:

To scale the voltage.  This apparently not necessary in this case, but I mention it here for completeness.  If the A/D input range is 0-3.3 V, then you have to amplify a small signal or attenuate a large one to use that range optimally.

To add a offset.  If a signal is centered around ground, for example, you can't simply multiply it by a constant to get it into the 0-3.3 V range.  A opamp circuit can add a offset while otherwise leaving the signal alone, or it can add a offset while also adding gain.

To present a lower impedance.  Actually this is a form of amplification.  Most microcontroller A/Ds want the input signal to have no more than 10 kΩ impedance.  Some fast ones even require down to a few 100 Ω to achieve full specs.  Many real world signals have much higher impedance than that.  A opamp buffer takes care of the high to low impedance conversion.

To clip the signal.  Microcontroller A/D inputs are often specified for very little voltage outside their operating range.  Even a little current thru the protection diodes can cause erratic microcontroller behavior, or result in erroneous A/D readings on other channels.  A rail to rail opamp running from the same supply as the microcontroller can't produce a signal outside the A/D range, but can be more tolerant to out of range signals on its input.  Those signals can be more easily clipped due to higher impedance being more tolerable at the input of the opamp than at the input of the A/D.  Also, opamps are generally a bit more forgiving of out of range input signals.

To isolate the raw signal from the A/D.  Most microcontroller A/Ds have a sample and hold front end.  This usually means charging a internal capacitor, which can put a significant load spike onto the signal.  If the signal is used anywhere else, these spikes as the sample and hold capacitor charges up can cause trouble.  By isolating the A/D input with a opamp, you keep the spikes from feeding back onto the raw signal, and probably also provide more drive to charge up the sample and hold more quickly.

To provide some filtering.  You'd like to eliminate all frequency content above half the sample rate.  Precise filtering is better done digitally after the conversion, but rough filtering before the conversion can be very useful.  It is also the only place filtering to avoid aliases can take place.  Once aliases are added by the sampling process, they become indistinguishable from the real signal in the frequency domain.

Comment: Does it hurt anything to put a single opamp after an analog MUX/before the ADC or do I need to have one opamp per channel?

Comment: @Pugz I think it may hurt if you are measuring very low voltages or if you have big common voltage in differential measurement. In these cases it's better to put amplifier before MUX. Can someone confirm my thoughts?

Comment: @OlinLathrop What about changing this sentence: "To present lower impedance" to "To present lower and constant impedance for ADC"?

Comment: @Pugz: If you are muxing multiple signals into a single A/D, and you need a opamp in there for whatever reason, then you have a choice whether to use one opamp per channel before the mux or a single opamp after.  Multiple amps can have lower settling time, especially if you are using active filters.  The single amp can buffer the signal so that the impedance of the mux doesn't matter much.  There are lots of tradeoffs.

Answer (score 1):

It's often the case that the input impedance of the ADC is relatively low, so that the ADC itself would load the circuit it is trying to measure and change the voltage. In that case it's better to add a buffer amplifier that can drive the low input impedance of the ADC while presenting a high-impedance to the circuit being measured.

Comment: What would you consider to be a low input impedance value? At what point do I really have to start worrying about the impedance changing the voltage reading?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that the gain of an Amplifier is not always the same along the frequency but you should know which is his Bode diagram and design it properly.
So also if you choose an unitary OpAmp (also called buffer) you should understand if your Vin(f) lies inside its unitary bandwidht, otherwise you will get a lower gain.

Not only the gain but also the phase changes and obiviously his input impedance changes.